# is there any plugin or example for app onboarding contextual focused tips for first time users

Tags: mobile, xamarin.forms

This is helpful for the first time users . 
Making the control focused and background blurred and moving to the next control . I need something like that in xamarin forms . Any suggestiom or help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks
Ganeshc[image]

Comment: Is there any plugin or example for app onboarding contextual focused tips in xamarin forms

Comment: You need to describe better what are you looking for and provide some sample of what you're been trying so far. By the way, read the [Xamarin Forms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) and read about the [Xamarin Forms Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry)

Comment: What controls are you talking about, you can explain them in detail, and you can attach a picture explanation.

Comment: Hi I have updated the question with details

Comment: @GaneshChennaiah If want to do Coach Marks,refer to this.(https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2019/01/17/xamarin-forms-coach-marks/)

Comment: Hi did u figure out the solution? Would u like to add the answer?